# Confusion regarding BrowserModule in Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, angular, module

I have a module `AppModule` and another module say `FooModule`. I have some components in `FooModule` and I' am loading routes of `FooModule` in `AppModule` like any normal app would do.

Following is the sample code for `AppModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from 'app/components/app';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'foo',
        loadChildren: './foo.module#FooModule'
      }
    ])
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Following is the sample code for `FooModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'

import { FooComponent } from 'app/components/foo';

@NgModule({
 imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: FooComponent
      }
    ])
    ],
    declarations: [FooComponent],
})
export class FooModule {}
```

Now when I run the app, I' am getting `Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.` error which as per my understanding shouldn't happen because I' am using `BrowserModule` in `AppModule` and loading routes of `FooModule` in `AppModule`.

Am I missing something?

I' am using `Angular CLI v1.2.0` and `Angular 4.2.5`.

### Edit

I know that to fix this issue I need to import `CommonModule` in `FooModule`. But that's exactly why I' am asking this question in first place that when I have imported `BrowserModule` in `AppModule` which re-exports `CommonModule` then why I need to include `CommonModule` in each individual module?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In each feature module, such as your `fooModule` you need to import `CommonModule`. It contains the common directives and pipes.

Actually, the `BrowserModule` imports and re-exports `CommonModule`, so they export the same functionality.

For more information, see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o&t=2s

UPDATE

Modules are not inherited. To say it another way, you cannot get the functionality of a module unless you import that module or another module that exports it.

[image: Imports Array Truth #3]

As shown in the above diagram... If Shared Module imports Forms Module and App Module imports Shared Module, App Module would not have access to the Forms Module component, directives, and pipes (such as ngModel in this example) unless Shared Module *exports* Forms Module.

KEY:

- Orange lines: Imports
- Gray lines: Exports
- Blue lines: Declarations

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I know that importing `CommonModule` in `FooModule` will solve the issue but that's exactly I' am asking that I have included `BrowserModule` in `AppModule` then why should I import `CommonModule` in every module?

Comment: Thanks for such great explanation. It seems I would need to import `CommonModule` in `FooModule` in-order for app to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Import `CommonModule` into `FooModule` and any other module. `BrowserModule` imports `CommonModule`. `CommonModule` contains `*ngIf` etc. directives